# js Вопрос по show() hide()

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно, чтобы при выборе в `select`значения `string` ниже появлялось текстовое поле, когда выбор `image` - было файловое поле.

**html**:

```
<label>Choose type</label>
<select name="type" id="type">
<option></option>
   <option value="string">String</option>
   <option value="image">Image</option>
</select>

<div id="string" style="display:none;">
<input type="text">
</div>

<div id="image" style="display:none;">
<input type="file">
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('#type').on('change',function(){
    var selection = $(this).val();
    switch(selection){
     case "string":
    $("#string").show()
    break;
     case "image":
    $("#image").show()
    break;
    default:
    $("#string").hide()
    }
});
```

Чтобы нижнее поле не выводило, когда ничего не выбрано - пишу функцию `hide()`. Но туда получается забить только одно значение. То есть `string` убирается, но `image` остается.

Вопрос: как в `hide()` прописать 2 значения, или переделать код в `js` ? В `js` не силен, пример нашел, нужно для `yii` фреймворка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот когда выбрано string

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда выбираю image то string ну продает ни как . 
Запутано написал, но надеюсь понятно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и снова метка php в вопросе о js, зачем?

Comment: @Naumov ну там же прозвучало, что `нужно для yii фреймворка` =)  А так - никто не мешает лишнюю метку убрать

Answer (score 2):

это дело логики, ты показываешь элементы, но не скрываешь

```
switch(selection){
     case "string":
    $("#string").show()
    $("#image").hide()
    break;
     case "image":
    $("#image").show()
    $("#string").hide()
    break;
```

и ставь запятые в конце строки

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#type').on('change',function(){
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $("#string,#image").hide();
    selection ? $("#"+selection).show() : false;
});
```